# How can I use an Asus WL-520GC router as a bridge/repeater?

Tags: router, internet, wireless-networking, relay

I live in a shared accommodation with one Internet connection, which is shared to multiple PC's though a wireless network.

Because the wireless router is at one end of the house and my room is at the other end, my computers and mobile devices have trouble picking up any signal.

What's the simplest way to fix this?

I had thought of putting my own wireless router - an Asus WL-520GC - half-way between the main router and my room. Perhaps it could relay the signal to my room.

Is this possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have an old unused router, you can check if its firmware supports any of following modes : wireless repeater, bridge or a client mode perhaps.

In case it doesn't work, next best solution would be verify if you can install custom firmware like [tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29) or [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index). [Here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) you can check if dd-wrt supports your router.

Third least expensive solution would be to try buying used router which support dd-wrt or maybe tomato.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wireless repeater;bridge;range extender/expander.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to extend your coverage is to attach external antenna to your wireless router, if it supports it. If not, you'll have to add repeater or second router and use them both in WDS mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same router.

I Just got an antenna off of amazon made by Asus.  It comes with a 6ft ish cable to.  Unscrew your 3db antenna and screw in the 9db antenna.  I now have perfect wifi through my apartment.  Even siting in the actual room of my asus router its faster than the small one 3db antenna it comes with. I get full bars going to my bedroom.  4 walls and some corners.

It was the best 20 bucks I have ever spent. Do this first.  If you a weak signal to begin with dont waste 70 plus buck on a repeater.  My friend did this and it barely works!!!

You will not regrett it.

This is second to my 20 dollar rice steamer I bought off amazon and that was a week before.
so throw that in there too if you have the cash.

Trust me!  you need both of these.